# Connecting to SQL Server in Visual Studio Code using Windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-code

I can't find where to enable my Windows authentication to be able to connect to SQL Server from Visual Studio Code.

I can find the server but it keeps wanting me to enter a password, but we connect to SQL Server using Windows authentication. I tried my Windows password and still no luck.

Can anyone help?

ERROR:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The target principal name is incorrect.)

Comment: The problem is the certificate on the server, not tj authentication method. Are you using a self signed cert?

Comment: When using SSL (really: TLS), make sure to specify the fully-qualified server name.